# Get a particular string from the input string

Tags: javascript, string, substring, indexof

I need to extract a particular string in javascript of format: “STATE:  ip  reachable” from another set of string I have as input.

From the extracted string, I need to extract both the numbers.

I have done so far is:

```
var str=<the input value>;

if(str.contains("STATE"))
{
var str = str.substring(str.indexOf("STATE"), string.indexOf("reachable");

}
```

I am finding difficulty in how to extract the numbers.

Comment: regular expression ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression...something like this:

```
var test = "STATE 10.0.0.18 192.168.42.9 reachable";
var ips = test.match(/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/g);
for (i = 0; i < ips.length; i++) {
    document.write(ips[i]);
    document.write("<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what are the 'numbers', but I tried that :

```
var str= "lorem ipsum STATE: 10.0.5.2 120.30.66.8 test ... blabla bla";

str = str.slice(str.indexOf("STATE"), str.length);
var tab = str.split(" ");
var num1 = tab[1];
var num2 = tab[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the pattern in the string, you can use below code :

```
var str = "STATE 10.0.0.18 192.168.42.9 reachable";

if (str.indexOf("STATE") >= 0) {
  var str = str.substring(str.indexOf("STATE ")+6, str.indexOf(" reachable"));
  var arrIP = str.split(" ");

  for (i = 0; i < arrIP.length; i++) {
      alert(arrIP[i]);
  }
}
```

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/4nx50b81/